# Controls are not working in FireFox but running in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox

I have an Application which runs fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. Things that don't work on Firefox include pop-ups, change of text on button on button click etc. I expect this is because of some missing script file that is required for Firefox.
So please help me with this...Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you give us some more information? It sounds like there is an error somewhere in your JavaScript that Firefox fails on but Chrome ignores. Could you check the web console in Firefox to see if there are error being displayed? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: Unfortunately nobody here can read minds, so post some code please :)

Comment: If it's missing scripts, get FireBug and go to the NET tab.  It'll show you exactly what didn't load.  Or, go to the console tab and see if there's an error being thrown that's preventing it from working.

Comment: _"Certainly it is because of Some Missing script file that are required for FireFox."_ - OK, so include the missing script file. (But why would FireFox _need_ more script files included than Chrome?)

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a javascript error happening on Firefox. As Eli commented above, please check the FireBug console in Firefox.